# Redirection link in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that allows me to add specific information and links. I have the bit of code that manages the link to a url. At the moment the link opens in the same tab meaning users leave our site. I need the link to open in a new tab. Not being a PHP developer I don't know how to do this an need some help. Here is the code:

```
<?php if ($launch) : ?>
            <div class="project-view">
                <strong><?php _e('Standard', 'themify'); ?></strong>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url($launch); ?>"><?php _e('View Standard', 'themify'); ?></a>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($launch) : ?>
        <div class="project-view">
            <strong><?php _e('Standard', 'themify'); ?></strong>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($launch); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e('View Standard', 'themify'); ?></a>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```